# TFS failover options for single server?

Tags: failover, team-foundation-server

What are people using for TFS (2005) failover when using a single server configuration?

It seems that most help docs from MS are about dual config (app and data tiers).   In fact I found a msdn blog post that said:

*"We do not provide any fail over options in single server configuration (MSDN Doc:      http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms316473(vs.90).aspx)"*

But the link provide above goes to a page that says "Content Retired", so not sure if that is out of date or what info was there.

Thanks for any info!

FK

[Edit]

As per Diago's comments ... Failover is probably the incorrect term.  I guess more to the point my question is "What are the backup & recovery strategies for single server TFS"?

I back up my database using standard back up practices, but what is the quickest way to get TFS back on line? How does mirroring the database fit into a single server config (or does it)?

(I'm not a sys admin so some of this is new territory for me.)

Comment: How do you want to implement failover. It is supported on both the AT and DT however not on single server for obvious reasons. What are you trying to prevent or failover exactly? Mirror the AT's?

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient i can think of is to use a complete disk image backup software like [Acronis True Image Echo Enterprise Server](http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/products/ATIES/). Server goes down, just restore entire image to another machine/disk and you are good to go. I have less to worry this way.